# What black magic is happening in my RSpec email uniqueness test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, unique, rspec2

I followed [The Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-uniqueness_validation), modified it, added Devise for user authentication and ran into an issue with the uniqueness tests of the email.

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(username: 'ExampleUser',
                     email:    'user@example.com',
                     password: 'passworD123')
    @user.save
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:username) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe 'username is already taken' do
    before do
      user_with_same_username = @user.dup
      user_with_same_username.username = @user.username.upcase
      user_with_same_username.email = 'a@b.c'
      user_with_same_username.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe 'email address is already taken' do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.username = 'differentUsername'
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  .
  .
```

Failures:

```
  1) User email address is already taken
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The uniqueness of email is set although it is not needed because Devise does it already. I changed `user_with_same_email.save` to `user_with_same_email.save!` and then I got a validation error for the email address because it's already taken:

```
1) User email address is already taken
   Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.save!
   ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
     Validation failed: Email has already been taken
   # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:101:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The return value of `user_with_same_email.save` is false and `it { should_not be_valid }` checks this case, but why is the test still failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your actual issue, the reason is simple: you're not testing upon the proper `subject`

Other guidelines:

- Do not save an object if you know it's invalid, you're just wasting time.
- Same for your first specs, do you really need a persisted object? I guess not..
- Last but not least: consider using factories, it's reusable and will let you have more consistent tests.

Here is what your specs could look like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  let(:user_attributes) { {
      username: 'ExampleUser',
      email:    'user@example.com',
      password: 'passworD123'
    }
  }

  subject(:user) { User.new(user_attributes) }

  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:username) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should be_valid }

  context 'with existing user in db' do
    before(:each) { user.save }

    describe 'username is already taken' do
      subject(:user_with_same_username) { User.new(user_attributes.merge(email: 'another@email.com')) }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe 'email address is already taken' do
       subject(:user_with_same_email) { User.new(user_attributes.merge(username: 'another name')) }
       it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes much more sense.